# My Keyboard and Mouse doesn’t work on dual boot Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I’m installing ubuntu20.04lts for the first time, And It’s installed along side windows 10, but, when I switch to Ubuntu OS, I can’t control the mouse or type. But, I can see the username I created when installing Ubuntu. Please Help.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is **not** a LTS release (*long-term-support* release), only the first release on a even year is a LTS, ie. "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 9 months for all flavours releasing with 20.10*" (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/10/22/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-released/).  You've also tagged 12.04 either in error, or for a reason that is very unclear (it's EOL or *end-of-life* thus off-topic on this site). It maybe some details of your machine may help, also if you're talking about desktop? server?

Comment: I assume that the keyboard and mouse was working properly during the live-session (before installing). Please describe your system. Is it a laptop? If so, does the touchpad work? What kind of mouse are you using? Does none of the keyboard-keys work?

Comment: Yes, The Keyboard & mouse worked during the live session, and its a HP Pavilion laptop, the touchpad & all keys work in windows. 
And I made a mistake earlier, it’s ubuntu 20.04